# reminder for comments/responses

Tags: discussion, feature-request, comments, answers

Suppose a user commented on my post and due to some reason I overlooked and then forgot.

As it is **my** question, the one who responded for my question would not care to write another comment if I do not respond for his/her previous comment. Same problem with comments to answers/comments/questions.

If some one post a comment doing @praphulla and I did not respond yet, Should there be a reminder kind of thing? In gmail it happens.

Is it possible to set such reminder? Does it happen in any other sites on overflow?

Comment: Well, not all comments need to be answered -- many are just for information. If there would be such reminders as you propose, I guess this would make people be swamped with that type of messages.

Comment: @StefanKohl As you said, it may be the case that some comments are just for information... In other cases What do you think is a reasonable thing to do?

Comment: So far I don't see a convincing reason to change anything in this respect at all.

Comment: @StefanKohl: A dismiss button could easily fix that. Are you really that swamped by comment responses?

Comment: @FrançoisG.Dorais: Yes, a dismiss button would certainly fix that.